# Change of coordinate in Hessian

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to show that the rank of Hessian on a smooth manifold is independent of coordinates.

Let $M$ be an $n$ dimensional smooth manifold and $f:M\to\Bbb R$ be a smooth map. Let $p\in M$ be a critical point of $p$. If $(U,\varphi)$ is a smooth chart at $p$, then the Hessian is defined as
$$\operatorname{Hess}_p(f) = \left[{\partial^2(f\circ\varphi^{-1})\over\partial x^i\partial x^j}(\varphi(p))\right]_{i,j}.$$

Suppose $(V,\psi)$ be another smooth coordinate at $p$ with coordinate $(\tilde{x}^i)$. Then
\begin{align*}
{\partial f\over\partial x^i}& = {\partial\tilde{x}^k\over\partial x^i}{\partial f\over\partial\tilde{x}^k}\\
{\partial\over\partial x^j}\left({\partial f\over\partial x^i}\right)& = {\partial\over \partial x^j}\left({\partial\tilde{x}^k\over \partial x^i}{\partial f\over \partial\tilde{x}^k}\right)\\
& = {\partial^2\tilde{x}^k\over \partial x^i\partial x^j}{\partial f\over \partial\tilde{x}^k}+{\partial\tilde{x}^k\over \partial x^i}{\partial\over\partial x^j}\left({\partial f\over \partial\tilde{x}^k}\right)\\
& = {\partial^2\tilde{x}^k\over \partial x^i\partial x^j}{\partial f\over \partial\tilde{x}^k}+{\partial\tilde{x}^k\over \partial x^i}{\partial\tilde{x}^l\over\partial x^j}{\partial^2 f\over \partial \tilde{x}^k \partial\tilde{x}^l}.
\end{align*}
Since $f$ has a critical point at $p$, ${\partial f\over \partial\tilde{x}^k} =0$ at $p$. Hence
$${\partial^2 f\over \partial x^i\partial x^j} = {\partial\tilde{x}^k\over \partial x^i}{\partial\tilde{x}^l\over \partial x^j}{\partial^2 f\over \partial\tilde{x}^k\partial\tilde{x}^l}.$$
This is what I got so far and I don't know what to do next from here. Please help.

Comment: The important thing to note is that because changes of coordinates are invertible, the matrices $\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^k}{\partial x^i}$ and $\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^l}{\partial x^j}$ have full rank.

Comment: It might help to write this as a matrix product. You should recognize the change-of-basis formula for a bilinear form (as opposed to linear transformation).